# HTML5 video repeat at a given timeframe

Tags: html, video, html5-video

I tried to create a `repeat` function associating with an HTML5 video element, so it allows the player to repeat at the given time frame that I want.

I will call this function in the following sequence, `repeat(1,3), repeat(5,7)` so I wish the player will repeat on time 1sec - 3sec when `repeat(1,3)` is called, then 5sec - 7sec when `repeat(5,7)` is called.

The player, however, keeps repeating time 1-3 sec frame when `repeat(5,7)` is called. I know the issue is that `video.currentTime >= 3` is true in `repeat(5,7)` and the player goes to time 1sec again. But I am not sure what to do. Shall I remove the eventListener when repeat(5,7) is called? What is the proper way to handle this?

```
repeat(startTime, endTime) {
  var video = document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0];
  video.addEventListener('timeupdate', function() {
    if (elem.currentTime >= endTime) {
      elem.currentTime = startTime;
      elem.play();
    }
  }, false);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to wrap the looping code in a named function so you can remove the old loop before setting up a new one. That is racked in `funcLoop` below

I have also added a check so that if you're in the old loop and trigger a new one then it moves to the start (not sure if you need that, but seemed to make it more complete)

```
<video id="video" controls="controls" muted preload="metadata" >
    <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
</video>
<button onclick="repeat(1,3)">1-3</button>
<button onclick="repeat(5,7)">5-7</button>

<script>
var funcLoop
function repeat(startTime, endTime) {
    var video = document.getElementById('video');
    video.removeEventListener('timeupdate', funcLoop, false);
    video.addEventListener('timeupdate', funcLoop=function(){
        if (video.currentTime < startTime) {
            video.currentTime = startTime;
        }
        if (video.currentTime >= endTime) {
            video.currentTime = startTime;
        }}, false);
    video.play();
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you! After comparing mine and your code, I realize I almost reached destination. My code has `removeEventListener` defined at begin of `repeat` function, but it turned out that my issue is  **defined the `funcLoop` inside `repeat` function`**.